# How do I get the size of a Vertica database?

Tags: database-size, vertica

I have a Vertica database. How can I tell how big the database is?

I need a rough answer for the purposes of reporting basic statistics about our environment to upper management.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways to get the size of a database, each suited to a slightly different use case. It's important to note that Vertica uses **raw** and **compressed** data in different ways, and that you should be conscious of which size you require. For example, licensing is based on the **raw** data size.

### Raw Size

The **raw** size is useful for capacity planning or monitoring license utilization (it's the space the data would take up if it wasn't compressed). To get the raw data size of the entire database, you can either use the [`GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#15563.htm) function, or query the system table `v_internal.license_audits`.

The `GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS()` function retrieves information about the most recent audit. [An audit](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#15450.htm) estimates the raw data size of the database and stores the information in `v_internal.license_audits`. By default, audits take place daily at 23:59 and can be configured or manually run.

Here's some example output:

```
dbadmin=> SELECT GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS();
                            GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Raw Data Size: 4.83TB +/- 0.24TB
License Size : 30.00TB
Utilization  : 16%
Audit Time   : 2014-05-11 23:59:49.763799+00
Compliance Status : The database is in compliance with respect to raw data size.

License End Date: 10/30/2014
Days Remaining: 171.18
```

If you have permissions, you can directly query the `license_audits` table:

```
SELECT /*+ label(license_utilization)*/
       audit_start_timestamp, 
       database_size_bytes / ( 1024^3 ) AS database_size_gb, 
       license_size_bytes / ( 1024^3 )  AS license_size_gb, 
       usage_percent 
FROM   v_catalog.license_audits 
ORDER  BY audit_start_timestamp DESC 
LIMIT  30;
```

Further, if you wish to get raw data size at the schema level, you can use this (from [vertica.tips](http://vertica.tips/2014/01/24/license-audit-utilization-raw-size/)):

```
SELECT /*+ label(estimated_raw_size)*/
       pj.anchor_table_schema, 
       pj.used_compressed_gb, 
       pj.used_compressed_gb * la.ratio AS raw_estimate_gb 
FROM   (SELECT ps.anchor_table_schema, 
               SUM(used_bytes) / ( 1024^3 ) AS used_compressed_gb 
        FROM   v_catalog.projections p 
               JOIN v_monitor.projection_storage ps 
                 ON ps.projection_id = p.projection_id 
        WHERE  p.is_super_projection = 't' 
        GROUP  BY ps.anchor_table_schema) pj 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT (SELECT database_size_bytes 
                           FROM   v_catalog.license_audits 
                           ORDER  BY audit_start_timestamp DESC 
                           LIMIT  1) / (SELECT SUM(used_bytes) 
                                        FROM   V_MONITOR.projection_storage) AS ratio) la 
ORDER  BY pj.used_compressed_gb DESC;
```

### Compressed Size

The **compressed** size is the actual size of the data on the disk. This is useful for estimating disk space usage as Vertica recommends that at least 40% of space is available at all times. You can get the compressed size from `column_storage` or `projection_storage` system tables.

Using `projection_storage` will also return any empty tables (from [vertica.tips](http://vertica.tips/2014/01/25/table-size/)):

```
SELECT /*+ label(compressed_table_size)*/
       anchor_table_schema, 
       anchor_table_name, 
       SUM(used_bytes) / ( 1024^3 ) AS used_compressed_gb 
FROM   v_monitor.projection_storage 
GROUP  BY anchor_table_schema, 
          anchor_table_name 
ORDER  BY SUM(used_bytes) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

A recent update changed the value v_catalog.licensing_audits from the constant "vertica" to three different values - Regular, Flex, and Total. If the original query does not provide reasonable results, try the following:

```
    SELECT /*+ label(estimated_raw_size)*/
       pj.anchor_table_schema, 
       pj.used_compressed_gb, 
       pj.used_compressed_gb * la.ratio AS raw_estimate_gb 
    FROM (SELECT ps.anchor_table_schema, 
                 SUM(used_bytes) / ( 1024^3 ) AS used_compressed_gb 
          FROM v_catalog.projections p 
          JOIN v_monitor.projection_storage ps 
          ON ps.projection_id = p.projection_id 
          WHERE  p.is_super_projection = 't' 
          GROUP  BY ps.anchor_table_schema) pj 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT (SELECT database_size_bytes 
                        FROM v_catalog.license_audits 
                        WHERE audited_data = 'Regular'
                        ORDER BY audit_start_timestamp DESC 
                        LIMIT  1) / 
                        (SELECT SUM(used_bytes) 
                         FROM V_MONITOR.projection_storage) AS ratio) la 
    ORDER  BY pj.used_compressed_gb DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below query you will get the exact size of table in [vertica](http://SELECT%20anchor_table_schema,%20anchor_table_name,%20SUM(used_bytes)%20/%20(1024/1024/1024/1024)%20AS%20TABLE_SIZE_GB%20FROM%20%20%20v_monitor.projection_storage%20GROUP%20%20BY%20anchor_table_schema,%20anchor_table_name%20order%20%20by%20sum(used_bytes)%20desc;).

```
SELECT anchor_table_schema,
anchor_table_name,
SUM(used_bytes) / (1024/1024/1024/1024) AS TABLE_SIZE_GB
FROM   v_monitor.projection_storage
GROUP  BY anchor_table_schema,
anchor_table_name
order  by sum(used_bytes) desc;
```

Explained below:

https://www.orahow.com/2018/06/how-to-check-size-of-tables-in-vertica.html